# Why array.shift() changes data-attribute grabbed with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How come the value of `$("#item").data("counter-values")` changes when I do `array.shift()`. I was expecting jQuery to read the DOM and get the data attribute every time I call it:

```
function test (values) {
  if (values.length) {
        values.shift()
        console.log(values)
        test(values)
    }
}
test($("#item").data("counter-values"))

(5) [12, 15, 29, 68, 9]
VM4843:4 (4) [15, 29, 68, 9]
VM4843:4 (3) [29, 68, 9]
VM4843:4 (2) [68, 9]
VM4843:4 [9]
VM4843:4 []
```

If I try to run it again then the array has no values:

```
test($("#item").data("counter-values"))
```

But if I get the element without jQuery then the data attribute is still there:

```
var t = document.getElementById('item');
var d = plant.getAttribute('data-counter-values');
d
"[308, 12, 15, 29, 68, 9]"
```

How can I preserve the value?

Comment: use `slice()`..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `jQuery.data` caching of 'data-*' attributes.
And `array.shift()` is a bang method which means it modifies the object that they’re being called on. So You are modifying cached data directly.

In the case You want to modify array data obtained by `.data()`, use `array.slice()`. Or You can use `jQuery.attr()` which read the DOM data without cache.